# Copying files (of a particular extension) remotely onto local computer preserving paths

Tags: linux, scp, find, path

I have bunch of files on the remote server.

I'm not interested in most of them, except for .pl files.

I want to get a copy of these on my local computer.

What is the best way to do this (at the same try preserving its path)?

I'm thinking somewhere along the lines of:

```
find . -name "*.pl" | xargs scp localuser@localip
```

Sadly doesn't do the trick. Anyone have better ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$rsync -av  --prune-empty-dirs --include-from=filter  user@remotesource/ target/

```
$cat filter

+ *.pl
+ */
- *
```

edit: typo

Comment: After a bit of modification, this also works. Now to decide which is the winner... decisions.

Comment: After checking the results, i found the rsync method copied all the .pl files while the find method (for some reason) skipped a substantial number of .pl files. So i have to award the answer to Rosco.

Comment: Even though i chose this as the answer, i find it rather inconvenient to create the extra filter file. I would have leant towards the find method if it did copy all the files.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
{
  find -type d -printf "mkdir %p\n" ;
  find -name "*.pl" -printf "put %p %p\n" ;      
} | sftp localuser@localip
```

Comment: Testing this first. Worked. Yay!

Comment: Sorry i can't upvote. i needz more reputation

Comment: @superspace You should mark the answer as "accepted" if it resolved your problem.